# Firebase Firestore can't save document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Summary**

I have a node server that is getting a document from MongoDB and then saving it to Firestore.  I have Firestore setup properly and I can save variables I create in node as a document but I can't save the document I get back from MongoDB.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?  Your help would be greatly appreciated!

**Error**

"Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "model" (found in field event.data). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator)."

***Code***

**Get stats from MongoDB & send to firebase**

```
 const objectFromMongoDb = await InstantComp.findOneAndUpdate(
                  {
                    _id: compId,
                    "competitors.userId": userObj._id,
                    inProgress: true
                  },
                  { $set: { "competitors.$.stats": lifeStats } },
                  { new: true }
                );

                addToFirestoreFunction(userObj._id, "NEW_COMP_DATA", objectFromMongoDb);
```

**addToFirestoreFunction**

```
async function addToFirestoreFunction(userId, eventType, data) {
  try {
    //read database
    //if userId contains eventType singleEntry then remove from database
    const timeStamp = new Date();
    userId = userId.toString();
    const userDoc = db.collection("pushData").doc(userId);
    const pushData = await userDoc.set(
      {
        event: {
          eventType,
          data,
          timeStamp
        }
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
    console.log("Document set in FireStore", pushData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("errpr pushing to firebase", err);
  }
}
```

**Object from MongoDB**

This is the object returned from MongoDB which I copied from a console log.

```
    {
                  inProgress: true,
                  _id: "5d63ffd3c364351ce81a230b", //an objectId from MongoDB
                  userId: "5cca01eb8c481129d711f479", //an objectId from MongoDB
                  compName: "Benji's Daily MuckShow",

                  competitors: [
                    {
                      inProgress: true,
                      _id: "5d63ffd3c364351ce81a230c", //an objectId from MongoDB
                      userId: "5cd65533c2e8700024309e6d", //an objectId from MongoDB
                      startingLifeTimeStats: [{kills: 0, wins: 10}],
                      stats: [{kills: 0, wins: 10}]
                    }
                  ]
                };``
```

Comment: What you added to your question looks like a regular JSON object, so is unlikely to cause this error message. I highly recommend including the actual code with how you get the error message in your question. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the article!  It was a great read and I'll definitely keep that in mind.  I updated the question to reflect the article's suggested structure.  I think the issue is because my object has ObjectIds from MongoDB in it?

Comment: Firestore wouldn't care about those. They're just string values without additional meaning. It's much more likely that the object from Mongo has additional metadata that is not being logged. You can most easily get rid of that by doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function addToFirestoreFunction(userId, eventType, data) {
  try {
    //read database
    //if userId contains eventType singleEntry then remove from database
    // Convert mongoose object to  normal json object
  data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    const timeStamp = new Date();
    userId = userId.toString();
    const userDoc = db.collection("pushData").doc(userId);
    const pushData = await userDoc.set(
      {
        event: {
          eventType,
          data,
          timeStamp
        }
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
    console.log("Document set in FireStore", pushData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("errpr pushing to firebase", err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this will be helpfull for you.